# Access column value as variable in Laravel Query Builder subquery function

Tags: laravel

I am trying to perform a conversion in a subquery function in Laravel query builder as follows.

```
DB::table('locations as locs')
    ->select('locs.time', 'sch.time')
    ->join('scheduled as sch', 'locs.id','sch.loc_id')
    ->where(function ($query){
         $converted = $this->convertTime('locs.time');
         //...
     })
  ...
```

What I can't figure how to do is access "`locs.time`" to be used in the function `convertTime`;

Comment: What does your `convertTime` method do?

Comment: You can't access it. If you want to format your data inside a query you'll need to use some sql functions to do so like date_format. What kind of dbms are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Also, what is your desired format and what format does the `locs.time` column have?